# SQL & Pivots - Aggregates and the syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Right I have a couple of questions related to SQL (MS SQL Server 2008 R2) and Pivots, in particular the "How To" part with a keen focus on the aggregate function that needs to be used.

Here is a set of data from two tables I am currently working on:

FirstTable

`EntryID    ReferenceID`
`694535     51`
`694536     51`
`694537     51`
`694538     51`
`694539     51`

SecondTable

`EntryID    AttributeName    ValueString    ValueInteger    ValueFloat    ValueDate`
`694535     Name             John           NULL            NULL          NULL`
`694536     Name             Anne           NULL            NULL          NULL`
`694537     Name             Jack           NULL            NULL          NULL`
`694538     Name             Lisa           NULL            NULL          NULL`
`694535     UserNumber       NULL           1               NULL          NULL`
`694536     UserNumber       NULL           2               NULL          NULL`
`694537     UserNumber       NULL           3               NULL          NULL`
`694538     UserNumber       NULL           4               NULL          NULL`

SecondTable can contain many more AttributeName entities like JoinDate (ValueDate), Surname (ValueString), etc. What I want to do is pivot the data such that the pivoted table has a set of unique EntryIDs that list the values of AttributeName as its columns, with the values in the Value columns populating those columns.

I'm not sure what aggregate function to use and when I should use those aggregate functions. Then the actual Pivot syntax seems to be getting me as well, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of a desired output table of data

Comment: @MrMarley, did the query worked for you?

Comment: @radar, thanks for the script and sorry for the late response. I've modified the script a bit to suit my actual tables but I'm getting a couple of more errors. I've uploaded a basic example of the data I'm actually working with here: <http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/465649/PivotQuestion.rar>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `coalesce` to get NON NULL value from the value columns and then do `PIVOT`

in case you know the list of attribute Names, you can list them similar to `Name` AND `UserNumber` other wise you need to use dynamic SQL to construct the column names list.

```
select T1.EntryID, [Name], [UserNumber] from 
(select EntryID, AttributeName, coalesce(valueString, valueInteger, ValueFloat, ValueDate) as Value from Table2) T2
pivot
( max(Value) for [AttributeName] in ( [Name], [UserNumber])
) pvt
join Table1 T1
on T1.EntryID = pvt.EntryID
```

output would be like

```
EntryID Name    UserNumber
694535  John    1
694536  Anne    2
694537  Jack    3
694538  Lisa    4
```